# Проблема с циклом for (python)

Tags: python, for

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
if a > b:
    for i in range(a, b):
        print(i)
else:
    for i in range(b, a):
        print(i)
```

Код должен выводить числа от А до В, если А>В и в обратном порядке в противном случае. Но у меня не выводит вообще ничего. Проблема в цикле скорее всего, но не могу понять где

Comment: примите ответ, если он вам помог — галочка слева от ответа

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
for i in range(a, b, a < b or -1):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
if a > b:
    for i in range(a, b):
        print(i)
else:
    for i in range(b, a, -1):
        print(i)
```